# How to use cell value instead of number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im sorry I dont even know how to correctly phrase this question.

The line of code I need to edit is this;

```
sheet.getRange(targetcell).setValue('=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("http://www.futbin.com/consumables/Position%20Change","table",2),"select Col2"),1)');
```

However instead of row 1, I want to use the value from cell G1.  So, something like this;

```
sheet.getRange(targetcell).setValue('=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("http://www.futbin.com/consumables/Position%20Change","table",2),"select Col2"),G1)');
```

However, this throws an error.

Could anyone advise how I can use the value in G1 instead of it being fixed?

Thank you.

Comment: About `However, this throws an error.`, can you provide the detailed error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try .setFormula instead of .setValue ...

```
sheet.getRange(targetcell).setFormula('=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("http://www.futbin.com/consumables/Position%20Change","table",2),"select Col2"),G1)');
```

Answer (score 0):

If there were a column G from the table that results from that IMPORTHTML function then you would use this:

sheet.getRange(targetcell).setValue('=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("http://www.futbin.com/consumables/Position%20Change","table",2),"select Col7"),1)');

Because G is column 7

However, there is only 3 columns from that IMPORTHTML. You can check this by entering the formular into a Google Sheet:

=IMPORTHTML("http://www.futbin.com/consumables/Position%20Change","table",2)

I suggest playing around with your formula in SHeets and once you've got what you want, go back into AppsScript.

Comment: Hi, sorry I think I have not explained it properly.

The cell containing the integer is in the active sheet (not in the table the data is being imported from).

So for example, in cell G1, I might have the number 4.  This means that I should be importing the data from the table in row 4.

i.e 

sheet.getRange(targetcell).setValue('=INDEX(QUERY(IMPORTHTML("http://www.futbin.com/consumables/Position%20Change","table",2),"select Col2"),G1)');

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, that looks like it should work to me. However, I think you want .setFormula rather than .setValue